# $D=\frac{d}{dx}$ , then the value of $\frac{1}{xD+1}(x^{-1})$ =?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

$D=\frac{d}{dx}$ , then the value of $\frac{1}{xD+1}(x^{-1})$ is-
[image]

My proof:

$\frac{1}{xD+1}(x^{-1})=y$ (say)

$y+xDy=x^{-1}$

$Dy+(\frac{1}{x})y=\frac{1}{x^2}$

$I.F= e^{p{dx}}=e^{ln(x)}=x$
$yx=\int \frac{1}{x^2} x {dx}+c$

$y=\frac{\ln(x) }{x}+\frac{c}{x}$

In particular, $ y=\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ is a solution
because, $(1+xD)(\frac{c}{x})=\frac{c}{x}+x(-\frac{c}{x^2})=0$

I don't know my proof is correct or not. Please give me solution if there is another. I think my proof is not perfect, please give me some hints. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that $\frac{d}{dx}$ really makes sense? Because generally derivative is ratio between two infinitesimals($\frac{dy}{dx}$) is it's representation in general. There should be something after $d$ so that it represents an infinitesimal.

Comment: your approach is fine.

Comment: @RAHUL What's on the LHS is operator notation. The whole fraction $1/(xD+1)$ is an operator that does something to whatever is to its right.

Comment: @Adrian Keister, hmm I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is fine.

Since this is an multiple choice question, we can also do the following to identify the correct choice:

\begin{align}(xD+I)\left[ \frac{\ln x}{x^k}\right]&=x\left[ \frac{x^{k-1}-kx^{k-1}\ln x}{x^{2k}}\right]+\frac{\ln x}{x^k}\\
&=\frac1{x^k}-\frac{k\ln x}{x^k} + \frac{\ln x}{x^k} \end{align}

We can see that $k=1$ eliminate the last two terms and give us our solution.

Comment: Yes, indeed, often on multiple-choice integration or solution problems it's faster to "test" the proposed integrals/solutions than to solve the problem oneself.

Answer (score 3):

$$(xD+1)y=xy'+y=x^{-1}$$ integrates immediately as $$xy=\log x+C.$$